# accessing nested container members

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to create a 2d array using nested containers. I want to print its members. Can anyone help me please.I am new to stl.
Thanx in advance.

```
typedef vector<int> v;
 vector<v>v1;
 v1.push_back(v(45,67));
 v1.push_back(v(36,89));
 v1.push_back(v(27,81)); 
 v1.push_back(v(18,78));
```

Comment: Can you paste the code what you have tried then we can throw some light

Comment: The constructor you have used for `v` is vector(size, value) which would actually construct a vector with first parameter and initialize all the elements with the second parameter. So as **ybungalobill** says, may be this is not what you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print the elements like this:

```
for(size_t i = 0, mi = v1.size(); i < mi; i++)
{
    for(size_t j = 0, mj = v1[i].size(); j < mj; j++)
        cout << v1[i][j] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Then you'll see that you actually created an array that contains:

```
{67,67,67,...,67}, // 45 times
{89,89,89,...,89}, // 36 times
{81,81,81,...,81}, // 27 times
{78,78,78,...,78}, // 18 times
```

Probably not what you expected.

Comment: That's helpful, but it would be even more helpful to explain how to get the probably-expected values into the right place ;-).